# Qual a forma correta de escolher os tipos das colunas?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, datetime, tipagem

Sempre vejo tabelas da seguinte forma. Ex:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id int(11) NOT NULL,
    titulo varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    autor varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    conteudo text NOT NULL,
    data varchar(11) NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

O porquê disso? Colocando `VARCHAR` em tudo é mais seguro que colocar o tipo correspondente ao campo?

Comment: Essas linhas estão completamente erradas. O que significa `identificação correspondente ao campo`?

Comment: Eu só não soube me expressar o nome dos campos certo, mas se conhece o banco de dados entende do que estou falando.

Comment: @Dias ñ entendi o que vc quer e nem qual é a sua dificuldade. Poderia ser mais especifico?

Comment: @gato CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `autor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `conteudo` text NOT NULL, 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: @Dias faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para vc aprender como utilizar o site e veja [como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `data` VARCHAR NOT NULL, (DUVIDA = Esses campos podem ter Date no local de varchar, ficaria mais seguro ou date e varchar tem o mesmo valor?)

Comment: @Dias se vc colocar `VARCHAR` o campo vai aceitar qualquer valor, já o tipo `DATE` ele só vai aceitar valores em formato de datas, tais como: `dd-MM-yyyy` ou `yyyy-MM-dd`, vc tem mais uma validação a mais. Porem vai depender do contexto e da finalidade.

Comment: @Dias da uma olhada na [especificação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) do Mysql em relação ao tipo date.

Comment: Obrigado, entendi, fiquei MUITO satisfeito com sua resposta. Obrigado Master.

Comment: @bigown - Tem como participar deste posta, obrigado. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172156/como-implantar-um-input-file-para-imagem?noredirect=1#comment354685_172156

Comment: O porque disso é simples: desconhecimento de quem fez. Data é data, varchar é varchar. O que é guardado dentro do campo não tem nada a ver com o que você vê na tela, por isso tem os tipos certos. Por exemplo, data guardada em varchar ou char costuma ser sinal de que a pessoa devia tentar outra profissão, ou estudar mais (tem exceções, mas quase sempre a pessoa acha que é o caso dela e não é).

Comment: @Dias Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

Todo tipo de coluna em uma tabela deve ser o mais adequado possível para a necessidade.

Se tem uma data, provavelmente precisa usar um tipo que tenha semântica de data. Se vai usar quantidades, deve usar um tipo numérico. Se vai apenas descrever uma informação, não importa como ela seja composta, vai usar um tipo texto. E assim por diante.

De fato o `varchar` costuma ser o preferido porque o grosso das informações de um banco de dados costumam ser apenas descritivas.

No exemplo se usar um `varchar` no lugar de um `date`, ou algo semelhante, terá dificuldade em classificar os dados em ordem cronológica, dependendo do formato, pode ter dificuldade de apresentação, será uma complicação extrema fazer cálculos com essa data (calcular vencimento, dias de atraso, faixa de dados, etc.)

Se o que deseja saber é porque os códigos das pessoas costumam ser tudo `varchar`, eu diria que é porque hoje a maioria das pessoas que resolvem desenvolver softwares não tem a menor noção do que estão fazendo. [Eles não sabem o que fazer, e linearizam tudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument). Como não sabem o que usar ou quando, usam uma coisa só que "funciona". A pessoa nem percebe a confusão que vai causar depois.

E pior, muitas vezes essas pessoas acabam ensinando outras  fazerem errado também. Por isso deve-se desconfiar de tudo o que se lê na internet. Pode parecer a coisa mais certa do mundo e estar errada, afinal quem está buscando a informação em geral não sabe avaliar se ela está certa.

Esse tipo de fenômeno ocorre porque as pessoas procuram aprender de cima pra baixo (em geral nunca chegam lá embaixo). Isso não funciona! O correto é aprender de baixo para cima, como ocorre na escola. Vai aprendendo um conceito mais básico, e dele vai indo para outros mais complexos que dependem dos conceitos anteriores.

E elas costumam continuar fazendo errado por causa do efeito [Dunning–Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

[image: As seen on the Internet]

Comment: Obrigado, entendi, fiquei MUITO satisfeito com sua resposta. Obrigado Master.

Comment: Tem como participar deste posta, obrigado. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172156/como-implantar-um-input-file-para-imagem?noredirect=1#comment354685_172156

Answer (score 1):

A "forma correta" é a que corresponde à finalidade que você dará ao armazenamento. É recomendável usar tipos numéricos para números, e `varchar` para string e textos. Entenda: Se você armazena tudo em `varchar` e depois precisar fazer cálculos cruzando dados pode ter uma surpresa desagradável, ou uma resposta imprecisa. Veja [isso](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/choosing-types.html).

Comment: Obrigado, entendi, fiquei MUITO satisfeito com sua resposta. Obrigado Master.

Comment: Marque a resposta que te ajudou pra que outras pessoas possam ser ajudadas tb ;)